# freedesktop launcher can't launch my app but it launches fine from terminal

Tags: gnome, .desktop, desktop-icons, activities-overview

I have installed an app which I can launch from terminal by typing "myapp".
`which myapp` yields `/path/to/myapp`, and I can launch the app by typing `path/to/myapp` in terminal. However, I'd really like to be able to launch the app from overview.

So I tried to create a .desktop entry like this:
`vi ~/.local/share/applications/myapp.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Exec=/path/to/myapp
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Comment=
Categories=Education;Utility
```

as well as `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/myapp.desktop`.
I've also tried putting the file in `/usr/share/applications`

The icon appears in my overview, but clicking it does nothing. If I add the line `Terminal=true`, a terminal window briefly pops up but does nothing. However, I've verified that typing `/path/to/myapp` in terminal definitely runs the app with no issues.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That an icon for your `.desktop` launcher appears in the application overview indicates that the launcher is correct. Launchers containing an invalid `Exec=` line simply would not become visible in the overview.

Thus, the reason why the app won't run from the launcher will be specific to the nature of the app. I do not see a generic reason why an app that runs from a terminal command would not run from a `.desktop` launcher. You will have to investigate your app more closely. One way to debug why the launcher may not work is to start it from the command line:

```
gtk-launch myapp
```

If it launches, the issue certainly is not with the launcher. If it does not launch, then the output in the terminal may give a hint as to why it does not launch.

Note: there is no need to make a `.desktop` launcher executable.

Comment: In the past, I had `.desktop` files with a bad `Exec=` line and they showed up in aplication overview but just didn't launch. I tried running `gtk-launch myapp` from terminal and it works perfectly, but if I run `gtk-launch /path/to/myapp`, it says "no such application". If I put `Exec=gtk-launch myapp` in my `.desktop` file, it continues to do nothing when I click on it from application overview. I also tried making the launcher with `alacarte`, but the behaviour is the same, so I agree that it's something to do with the app. The app is built from source, but installed as a binary in `$HOME`.

Comment: Whoops.... I tried again and it looks like neither `gtk-launch myapp` or `gtk-launch /path/to/myapp` work. So, if `.desktop` files use `gtk-launch`, then that explains why clicking on the icon in applications overview does nothing.

Comment: I already answered knowing I had too little information, because apparently you do not want to give specific information. I indicated that `gtk-launch myapp` could provide output, but you do not feel like providing information on that as well. Want specific help, then provide detail. Otherwise, accept this answer and proceed..

Comment: I think when I ran `gtk-launch myapp`, it just didn't do anything. It printed no output. Since I haven't yet found a solution to this issue, I guess I'll just accept your answer. Kudos!
btw, Vanadium is my favourite element.